# The system cannot find the path specified: do I fix by adjusting imported module variable, set environmental variable, other?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have been following along with a tutorial that had me load a model to change the last activation layer and then apply those changes to the previous model (saving a new model?).  My question is do I have to change the module filepath (if so how do I do that from an imported module) or do I have to make sure an environmental variable is set? or something else?

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

layers_info = {}
for i in model.layers:
    layers_info[i.name] = i.get_config()

layer_weights = {}
for i in model.layers:
    layer_weights[i.name] = i.get_weights()

#importing the required modules
from vis.visualization import visualize_activation
from vis.utils import utils
from keras import activations
from keras import applications
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18,6)

layer_idx = utils.find_layer_idx(model,'predictions')

#changing the activation of the layer to linear
model.layers[layer_idx].activation = activations.linear

#applying modifications to the model
model = utils.apply_modifications(model)
```

Error

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vis\utils\utils.py in apply_modifications(model)
    122     try:
--> 123         model.save(model_path)
    124         return load_model(model_path)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1084         from ..models import save_model
-> 1085         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1086 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    104 
--> 105         f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='w')
    106         opened_new_file = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, **kwds)
    268                 fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, **kwds)
--> 269                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
    270 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    104     elif mode == 'w':
--> 105         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    106     elif mode == 'a':

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '/tmp/w9mydjzc.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-a64a2adb4a8c> in <module>()
      5 
      6 #applying modifications to the model
----> 7 model = utils.apply_modifications(model)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vis\utils\utils.py in apply_modifications(model)
    124         return load_model(model_path)
    125     finally:
--> 126         os.remove(model_path)
    127 
    128 

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/tmp/w9mydjzc.h5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the /tmp/ folder is missing. Try either adding a period in front `./tmp/` or creating the folder first.

Comment: I will test this out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: so technically this worked so I will obviously accept it. I am more curious though how to alter the filepath in .activations()  to avoid having to make files. I will make a new questions for that.